# not found showing twice in 404 page?

Tags: php, wordpress

in the 404.php page my original message is showing correctly, but i also get a second message in the footer, I checked all files and googled a lot about this issue but got no results.

this is the live example: http://www.rapyemen.org/?page_id=181

can anyone help to to solve this issue of getting two 404 messages?

this is my 404.php code:

```
    <div id="container">

        <?php 
            // action hook for placing content above #content
            nd_abovecontent();

            // filter for manipulating the element that wraps the content 
            echo apply_filters( 'nd_open_id_content', '<div id="content">' . "\n\n" );

            // action hook for placing content above #post
            nd_abovepost(); 
        ?>

            <div id="post-0" class="post error404">

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but we were unable to find what you were looking for. Perhaps searching will help.', 'thematic' ) ?></p>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <form id="error404-searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
            <div>
                <input id="error404-s" name="s" type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" size="40" />
                <input id="error404-searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Find', 'thematic' ); ?>" />
            </div>
        </form>


            </div><!-- .post -->

            <?php 
                // action hook for placing content below #post
                nd_belowpost(); 
            ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

        <?php 
            // action hook for placing content below #content
            nd_belowcontent(); 
        ?> 

    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php
// action hook for placing content below #container
nd_belowcontainer();

// calling the standard sidebar 
nd_sidebar();

// calling footer.php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Where it is supposed to land ?

Comment: Its appearing you are pre-pending your 404 code to the default Apache 404 error page. See the page having: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>` at the end of the page. I think this might be a server config issue. Can you post any `.htaccess` files you have?

Comment: @crypticツ I don't think so. His other pages are working fine.

Comment: @Sahal because his other pages are not 404 errors. You are misunderstanding the question. OP wants to know why error appears TWICE, not why the 404 is occurring.

Comment: HTML Body element says like this `<body class="error404 windows firefox ff17">`. That means he landed in proper error page.

Comment: at DaveRandom i've posted my code. at sahal i don't want to display the another 404 text showing after the footer, @cryptic that is the problem, how can i solve it ?

Comment: yes cryptic that's the problem..

Comment: @crypticツ Where error page appearing twice ? OR error content appearing twice ?. I have clicked the link he has given. Page land to the `Wordpress Error Page`

Comment: at cryptic my .htaccess is empty

Comment: @Sahal look at middle of page and look at bottom. Not Found error twice.

Comment: Ohh yaah, I haven't seen that. So got confused :)

Comment: @user1564354 what are your php.ini settings for `auto_append_file` and `auto_prepend_file` run `phpinfo();` in above code to see.

Comment: @user1564354 can you temporarily make the above code an empty file? `404.php` empty file then. I want to check to see if the PHP code is inserting the Apache error.

Comment: You are not running Apache but Nginx, so it is WP inserting the error. I'm not sure where to proceed from here as the error can be occurring either due to WP core or the theme, both of which I can't help debug without access to the code and a test environment. Hopefully someone can help out, sorry. =o(

Comment: can i use my .htaccess to hide this error, or if all Nginx errors?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there is no page id called `118`.

For example your `Contact Us page work fine with page id of`208`.

Make sure you are passing correct page id.